# How to use conditionPanel to update display different sliderInput in Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

I want to use ConditionalPanel to display different sliderInput in Shiny according to user's selectInput.

But the output is always from the first sliderInput.

How can I achieve it?

Here is my example code:

```r
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput("Type", "Type", c(A = "A", B = "B")),
    conditionalPanel(
      condition = "input.Type == 'A'",
      sliderInput(inputId = "hi", label = "", min = 0, max = 10, value = 5, step = 1)
    ),
    conditionalPanel(
      condition = "input.Type == 'B'",
      sliderInput(inputId = "hi", label = "", min = 10, max = 100, value = 50, step = 1)
    ),
  ),
  mainPanel(
    verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "text")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$text <- renderPrint({
    input$hi
  })
}  

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `inputId`s have to be unique, i.e. even if you wrap inside `conditionalPanel` you are creating two inputs, which depending on the condition are visible or not.

Hence, to make your code work use unique IDs and take care of that in the server using e.g. a `switch` to conditionally display the value of the visible slider:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput("Type", "Type", c(A = "A", B = "B")),
    conditionalPanel(
      condition = "input.Type == 'A'",
      sliderInput(inputId = "hiA", label = "", min = 0, max = 10, value = 5, step = 1)
    ),
    conditionalPanel(
      condition = "input.Type == 'B'",
      sliderInput(inputId = "hiB", label = "", min = 10, max = 100, value = 50, step = 1)
    ),
  ),
  mainPanel(
    verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "text")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$text <- renderPrint({
    switch(input$Type,
      A = input$hiA,
      B = input$hiB
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Or as a second option use one `sliderInput` which you could update conditionally on the user's choice using an `observe`er and `updateSelectInput`.

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput("Type", "Type", c(A = "A", B = "B")),
    sliderInput(inputId = "hi", label = "", min = 0, max = 10, value = 5, step = 1)
  ),
  mainPanel(
    verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "text")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  observe({
    switch(input$Type,
      A = updateSliderInput(inputId = "hi", min = 0, max = 10, value = 5),
      B = updateSliderInput(inputId = "hi", min = 10, max = 100, value = 50)
    )
  })
  output$text <- renderPrint({
    input$hi
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```